# AnimatedVectorDrawable or AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat both crashes on different api levels

Tags: android

This code works on Lollipop:

```
drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.list_2_map_animated_vector_drawable)!!
(drawable as AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat).start()
```

But on Oreo it crashes with this exception:

```
Process: com.tractrac.otrack.debug, PID: 23424
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable cannot be cast to android.support.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat
    at com.myprettyapp.main.MainActivity$onCreate$6.onClick(MainActivity.kt:177)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6303)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24828)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Changing to `(drawable as AnimatedVectorDrawable)` makes it work fine on Oreo but gives the exact same crash in Lollipop but opposite.

I thought `AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat` would work for both.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For API 24 and above, this class is delegating to the framework's AnimatedVectorDrawable. For older API version, this class uses ObjectAnimator and AnimatorSet to animate the properties of a VectorDrawableCompat to create an animated drawable.

Comment: Use object Animator class for previous API version

Comment: I get a runtime error: `XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag animated-vector` when using compat for api 19